# Delete Row if string is found in any columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

My comment database just got slammed with over 11,000 spam entries. I am trying to think of a way to delete any entry with a specific word in it. There are about 12 columns per entry and I want to search all of those columns and if there are any of the "keywords" in there then delete that row. Something like:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE colum1, column2, column3 = has the substring xanaxs;"
```

Please help so I don't have to delete 11,000 rows.

Comment: whats `column1 = 'blabla-xan'` and `column2 = 'axs-blabla'`, do you want to delete that row or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could concatenate all the columns together:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE concat(column1,column2,column3) like "%xanaxs%";
```

Answer (score 1):

From a strict SQL point of view, you would have to do it one by one, as in: `DELETE FROM comments WHERE column1 LIKE '%first_string%'`

However, since you're in PHP, you can loop it per column and keyword, as long as you put each in an array.

Answer (score 0):

ry this:

```
"DELETE FROM comments WHERE CONCAT_WS(colum1,column2,column3) LIKE '%xanaxs%'"
```

Comment: Cybernate, just had a question does the % & % on either side equal an exact match? Case and all?

Comment: No % is a wild card in the search, hence the query would return all rows where the xaxaxs is anywhere in the column value.